# Is it true that $\pi(G/H, x_0) \cong \pi(G, x_o)/ \pi(H, x_0)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that

$$
\pi(G/H, x_0) \cong \pi(G, x_o)/ \pi(H, x_0) \text{?}
$$

if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: (I am assuming that by $\pi$ you mean the fundamental group.)  Then a counter-example would be G = R (real numbers), H = Z (integers). The quotient G/H is homeomorphic to a circle. Its fundamental group is non-trivial (isomorphic to H, in fact) and therefore not a quotient of the fundamental group of G, which is trivial. There are many many more counter-examples; why did you expect this isomorphism to exist?

Comment: @Parisien That should be an answer.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff okay, done. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If by $\pi$ you mean the fundamental group, then this is not true. Here is a counter-example:

Take $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$. The quotient $G / H$ is homeomorphic to a circle $S^{1}$ via the exponential map $t \mapsto \operatorname{exp}(2\pi it)$. But the fundamental group of the circle is non-trivial (in fact, it is isomorphic to $H$) so it can not arise as a quotient of $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{R}) = \{1\}$.

This sits in line with a more general class of counter-examples: Start with any Lie group $L$. If $L$ is not simply-connected, say $\pi_{1}(L) \cong H$, then we can associate to it the so called *universal covering space*. (You can read about this in the first chapter of Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.) In our case, the universal covering space is a simply connected Lie group $G$ together with a covering map $p \colon G \to L$ which is at the same time a homomorphism of Lie groups. Again by the theory of covering spaces (see Hatcher) we have $\ker \ p = H$, so that $G /  H = L$. But $\pi_{1}(L) = H$ and $\pi_{1}(G) = 0$, so again $\pi_{1}(L)$ does not arise as any quotient of $\pi_{1}(G)$.
A concrete example of this would be to take $L = PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Then $G = SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and the covering map $p \colon SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is exactly the quotient $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \twoheadrightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\pm 1\} = PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$

More generally, if you have a simply connected Lie group $G$ and a Lie subgroup $H$ acting properly discontinuously on $G$ then $\pi_{1}(G/H) \cong H$...

If you have any questions left please feel free to ask them.